# Grid ComponentColumns, How To Focus Component?

Tags: c#, extjs

I have a grid with component columns, and I need to focus the first component cell to start edit, so how to focus the TextTield for example in the Component Column
All I can get is:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().setCurrentPosition({ row: 0, column: 0 });
```

and it's select the cell not the component ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the grid editing plugin i believe the method is `startEdit`.  More info available in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-method-startEdit).

```
var plugin = grid.getPlugin('myPluginId');
plugin.startEdit(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank u, but the grid without editing plugin, only Component Columns, actually I found solution like this:

```
grid.getView().focusCell({ row: 0, column: 0 });
```

if doesn't work with you, try to set time out:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    grid.getView().focusCell({ row: 0, column: 0 });
}, 100);
```

or maybe set delay for event which call this instruction, hope it helps